# jQuery bug? ("this" members disappear)

Tags: jquery, runtime-error

https://jsfiddle.net/a1eds7m0/1/

```html
<form id="form" onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;">
  <p><input type="text" id="arWalletKeyFile" name="arWalletKeyFile"/></p>
</form>
```

```js
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.arKeyChooser = function(options) {
        this.options = options || {};
    }

    $.fn.arKeyGet = function() {
        if(!this.options) alert("jQuery bug?")
    }

}( jQuery ));

$(function() {
    $('#arWalletKeyFile').arKeyChooser({storeName: 'authorARPrivateKey'});
    $('#arWalletKeyFile').arKeyGet()
});
```

`this.options` mysteriously disappears. Is this a jQuery bug or what? What is a workaround?

Comment: There isn't only one "global" jQuery instance. Every call of the constructor (e.g. `$('#arWalletKeyFile')`) creates a new jQuery instance.

Comment: @Andreas So where to store the data like `options`, if I can't store in `this`?

Comment: Store the instance you're modifying and use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign value to an jQuery wrapper object returned by `$()` function. Try to use [`data()` method](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead (which will associate it with your `input [type=file]` HTML element):

```
$.fn.arKeyChooser = function(options) {
  // set options
  this.data('options', options || {});
}

$.fn.arKeyGet = function() {
  // get options
  const options = this.data('options');
  if(options) {
    alert("jQuery bug?");
  }
}
```

also, I would recommend to `return this;` in each your jQuery plugin, so it remains chainable.